# find data inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_sequence] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_sequence] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [Colour] => Black 
                )

        )

)
```

whats the best way to search this array by the `product_sequence`

i tired using:

```
array_search('1', $_SESSION["cart"])
```

but this doesnt return any data at all

Comment: The best way is to use `foreach`

Comment: would that be the quickest way too?

Comment: What do you mean by "search"?  You just want the arrays that have product_sequence = 1?

Comment: WIth this array structure `foreach` is the **only** way

Comment: `array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_sequence")` for php >= 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this

To find values that match your search criteria, you can use `array_filter` function:

for value:

```
$searchword = '1';
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); })
```

for key:

```
$searchword = 'last';
$matches = array();
foreach($example as $k=>$v) {
    if(preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $v)) {
        $matches[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` or you can use `array_filter`. A simplified example:

```
<?php

$products = [
    [
        'product_sequence' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'product_sequence' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'product_sequence' => 2,
    ]
];


$productSequence = 1;

$filteredProducts = array_filter($products, function($product) use ($productSequence) {
    // only return elements that test `true`
    return $product['product_sequence'] === $productSequence;
});

print_r($filteredProducts);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_sequence] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_sequence] => 1
        )

)
```

More reading:

- [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
- [Anonymous functions and the `use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Hope this helps :)